# What is a good way to generate a string unique to each pc, the same each time on a given pc, works for Win, Linux, and Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am wondering if anyone has any recommendations on how I could go about generating a string based on probably something to do with the host pc's environment so that each PC would probably have a different string but each time it runs the string would always be the same on a given pc that would work for Windows, Linux, and Mac if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mac address **should** be a unique ID

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
```

Comment: It should be - depends how "utils" like macchanger effect this module.

Comment: its not bulletproof ... but it should solve the problem if you are not (very) concerned with "malicious" actors

Comment: I will definitely give this a go. I appreciate it.

Comment: I am wondering about this method in a server environment, would it be reliable if it's running on a virtualized machine?

Comment: if you clone another machine the mac address will be the same ... if you create a new machine it should have a new mac address (you can also hardcode these yourself to unique values in your virtualized environment)